# Fix Appendix formatting

Tags: margins, page-numbering, sharelatex

For my thesis I'm adding various appendices to the end.  However, for some reason the formatting changes for the appendices.  The margins completely disappear, making the text go right up to the edge of the page.  Also, the page numbers disappear.  I've tried using the \geometry package, changing \appendix to \begin{appendix} but none of them have any effect on the formatting.

```
\usepackage{booktabs} % for better tables
\usepackage{microtype} % for better typography
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}  % for urls
\usepackage{showkeys} % shows labels during draft mode
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{geometry}
.
.
.
\input{chap1.tex}
\input{chap2.tex}
\input{chap3.tex}
\input{chap4.tex}

\appendix
\input{app1.tex}
\input{app2.tex}
\input{app3.tex}
\input{app4.tex}
```

I'm using the UTPA thesis class from [UTPA Thesis Template Github](https://github.com/ggarza/UTPA-Thesis-Template)
and running it on ShareLatex.  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

How it looks:
[image]

Comment: Can you create a small document which exhibits these properties?  Try removing each chapter/appendix one at a time.

Comment: Already tried removing  each chapter/appendix but makes no difference.  I uploaded a sample document to github,

https://gist.github.com/macroxela/f3276b573ecd093f249e

Comment: Please add your example here on TeX.SX, once your repo will be gone, this question will be useless to everybody.

Comment: Case in point: The gist is not accessible any more. I'll agree with the close vote, without the MWE this is hard to investigate.